# CLI - refreshing multi-line output in terminal with click

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I am trying to write a script with a CLI. I am using [click](http://click.pocoo.org) to do so, in this case I mostly need it's `click.getchar` function for resposnive interaction.

Not to clutter my terminal and for better readability I would like to *rewrite* my output. As `\r` only works for single lines, the only manageable solution I found for this is [reprint](https://github.com/Yinzo/reprint). However reprint works only with it's list or dictionary, and hence is not compatible with [click](http://click.pocoo.org)'s `click.echo` and `click.prompt`. An ugly workaround would be `click.clear`, but I would like to avoid this if possible.

Is there any nice solution to this? I would also not mind using a different package than [click](http://click.pocoo.org), if there is something more suitable.